# Hiding confidential text files on local server

Tags: http, server

I'm testing a website using a python http.server.

I'm accessing the server via localhost.

There are some direct object references. *(e.g. if I head straight to the text file, localhost:8000/logs.txt)* I am able to access the file.

What's the best method to hiding the log file from the outside world? I'm currently encasing the txt in many folders using the technique security through obscurity.

I was just wondering if there are any other methods to keep the file on the server, but hide it from others.

I'm not entirely sure I can change the permissions of this file either.

Regards
Elgar

Answer (score 0):

Usually if your http server is setup to serve static files (that is files read from file system and not dynamic content generated as part of handling the request), you want to set the root of serving the files to a directory that contains only files you want the clients to be able to access. Any files you don't want to be accessible from your http server should live outside that serve root directory.

The exact changes you have to make to your code depends on how you implemented it. If you can share your current code we will be able to provide more specific assistance. But the idea remains the same, your root path exposed on the http server will correspond to an `assets` directory or similar and you should not have any sensitive information underneath that directory. Most web servers implement this pattern and can potentially implement additional access control measures on top to further restrict who can access the exposed files

Comment: Thanks, I currently have all files in one folder and then two php files in the cgi-bin.